# json to human readable date date shows one less than actual date

Tags: android, json, date

I convert json date to human readable date but it shows less one then actual date. I 
used this code to convert it:

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            Long timeInMillis =    Long.valueOf(AttendanceModelList.get(position).getEmpdate());
            calendar.setTimeInMillis(timeInMillis);
            Date date=new Date(timeInMillis);
            viewHolder.textemployeedate.setText(df.format(date));
```

Please help

Comment: Probably a time zone effect. You should try to set the appropriate zone on your `SimpleDateFormat`-object.

Comment: But i Didnt use Time Zone i Write only the Above code for date

Comment: Even if you don't explicitly write the time zone Java will set it for you, in your case the system time zone. A calendar date is not the same overall in the world.

Comment: Then how can i solve it can you plese guide me with a modified code plese help i am getting still this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say as summary:

> Your calendar date is one day less than expected when you try to
>   interprete a global timestamp of type `java.util.Date` as calendar
>   date.

This phenomenon can happen due to timezone effects or midnight change. Before viewing the technical solution, you have to ask yourself:

- What is your default (system) timezone using `TimeZone.getDefault()`?
- Do you run your code on a server which has not the expected timezone?
- In which timezone do you wish to view the calendar date? (the timezone associated with your expected "actual" date)

**How to specify the timezone?**

```
java.util.Date d = ...; // from your JSON-timeInMillis?
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String tz = "Asia/Kolkata"; // or any other valid tz id
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(tz));
System.out.println(sdf.format(d));
```

Comment: hey meno sir i set the time zone as u tell me but still having the same issue.

Comment: @shivpaljodha It would be helpful if you tell us the timezone of the machine you are running your code on. Second: What kind of code makes you thinking that there is one day less. A short but complete compilable example would be nice (SCCE), but I have not the impression that you have given such a SCCE.

Comment: @shivpaljodha And I strongly hope that you don't base your statement on watching the confusing output of `java.util.Date.toString()` which uses the system timezone.

Comment: i think You Are Right it May Be Time Zone Issue My Code Show Right Date On Actual Device But on imulator i am still Suffering With This issue thanks for your Help.